# Howto Select rows that match the intersection of multiple rows in other tables in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, select, intersection

It seems complicated (and probably it is). But i cant imagine how to solve this.

There are tables:

**COMPANIES**
*id | name*
1 | Google
2 | Samsung
3 | Microsoft

**PARAGRAPHS**
*id | name*
1 | Header
2 | Body
3 | Footer

**TAGS**
*id | tag*
1 | Internet
2 | Softwate

**COMPANIES_VS_TAGS**
id | company_id | tag_id
1 | 1 | 1
2 | 2 | 2
3 | 3 | 1
4 | 3 | 2

**PARAGRAPHS_VS_TAGS**
id | paragraph_id | tag_id
1 | 2 | 1
1 | 2 | 2

I need to select all companies, that belongs to [any_number] of tags that belongs to paragraph by **logical AND**.

So, in the example above, the Body paragraph should output the only company "Microsoft".

ADD: I can use **only WHERE and SubQueries**: this is the limitation of CMS i have to use.

Answer (score 1):

Learn how `INNER JOIN` works.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: I forgot to mention (SORRY) - I can use only WHERE and subqueries. This is the limitation of the cms i have to use.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to join all your tables:

```
SELECT companies.id, 
       companies.name 
FROM   companies, 
       tags, 
       companies_vs_tags, 
       paragraphs_vs_tags 
WHERE  companies.id = companies_vs_tags.company_id 
       AND tags.id = companies_vs_tags.tag_id 
       AND tags.id = paragraphs_vs_tags.tag_id 
       AND paragraphs.id = paragraphs_vs_tags.paragraph_id 
       AND paragraphs.name = "Microsoft";
```

Comment: Soory, but this query (minus last line) produces logical **OR**, so as a reasult I'm getting all the companies(((

Comment: I need the company that have **BOTH** tags at the same time